# Why is this happening ,scope of res.redirect() method is confined to findByIdAndRemove method in express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

If i am writing a res.redirect() in findByIdAndRemove scope then it redirecting it to new updated page but if i am putting redirect method outside that method scope its not redirecting it to updated page,
i have to manually hit refresh button on browser. can someone explain it to me what's happening?

```
app.post('/delete',function (req,res) {

Item.findByIdAndRemove(req.body.checkbox, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);

        } else {
            console.log('Successfully deleted record!');

        }
           res.redirect('/')
    })

                                        **<--- but if i write it here it's not working!**

})
```

*Detailed explanation would be appreciated ,I just started learning express and mongoDB
sorry in advanced for my silly question.*

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?  What exactly happens?  Please describe your problems here in much more detail than just saying it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Item.findByIdAndRemove()` is asynchronous.  That means its callback gets called sometime later, after you function has returned. So, anything you want to execute after `Item.findByIdAndRemove()` has finished has to be inside its callback.  This is standard asynchronous behavior in node.js.

So, when you put the redirect outside the callback, it executes BEFORE the database operation has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use async/await model instead of callbacks, it's cleaner and easier:

```
app.post('/delete',async function (req,res) {
  await Item.findByIdAndRemove(req.body.checkbox);
  res.redirect('/somewhere/else');
});
```